# MySQL delete with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is this the right way the perform delete on Mysql table "b25h3_k2_items"
I want to delete all terms within these condition, except for 10 rows. 
(overall 20K).

```
DELETE FROM `medicycle`.`b25h3_k2_items` WHERE (`b25h3_k2_items`.`id`
> 100) AND (`b25h3_k2_items`.`hits` < 100);
```

When I run this I get Error 500 After short time. Is it a matter of server or code? 
2. can only server admin do such queries? how to fix such issue

Comment: missing a `=` or just a typo?

Comment: @Mihai I guess it was the format >

Comment: You have to have DELETE privileges, please post the entire error msg.

Comment: @sagi I received Error 500 from server (query in phpmyadmin)

Comment: Ok it seems to be resolved, I managed to drop 450 queries over phpmyadmin and 20K queries with my code before that. not sure the reason for the error